# Firebase Cloud Storage Security Rules Restrict Custom Meta Data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-security

I want to control what key user can create for custom meta data

```
uploadBytes(ref, blob, { customMetadata: { a: 1 } } )
```

for example I want user to be able to create only key `a`

I tried:

```
allow create: if request.resource.metadata.diff(resource.metadata).affectedKeys().hasOnly(['a'])
```

but it denied the permission

what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the solution

```
allow create: if request.resource.metadata.keys().hasOnly(['a'])
```